# htaccess rewrite slashes to dashes in parameter url

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rewrite setup that works for 90% of my parameter url rewrites, but I have a few instances where the parameter name contains a slash.

I need to replace the slash "/" with a dash "-" for obvious reasons. How can I do this?

> Old URL: domain.com/medications/?drug=medication-title/has/slashes
>
> New URL: domain.com/medications/medication-title-has-slashes

**Current Code:**

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^medications/([^/]+)/?$ medications/?drug=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Came up with a PHP resolution for this instead. But leaving open if someone finds a solution for this.

**PHP:**
$str = str_replace("/", '-', $str);